# Equals validation vs indexOf validation?

Tags: java, performance

I need to validate if one String contains the char `$`  before replace this one.

I did two implementations for this propose.

The first implementation always execute `replace(char oldChar, char newChar)`  and `equals(Object anObject)` as validation.

```
String getImportLine(Class<?> clazz) {
    String importLine = toSanitizedClassName(clazz.getName());
    String importStaticLine = importLine.replace('$', '.');
    if (importLine.equals(importStaticLine)) {
        return String.format("import %s;", importLine);
     } 
    return String.format("import static %s;", importStaticLine);
}
```

This implementation parses the string two times with:

- `importLine.replace('$', '.')`
- `importLine.equals(importStaticLine)`

---

The second implementation uses `indexOf(int ch)` as validation and `replace(char oldChar, char newChar)` in the worst case.

```
String getImportLine(Class<?> clazz) {
    String importLine = toSanitizedClassName(clazz.getName());
    if (importLine.indexOf('$') == -1) {
        return String.format("import %s;", importLine);
    }
    importLine = importLine.replace('$', '.');
    return String.format("import static %s;", importLine);
}
```

The second implementation, in the worst case, parse the string two times  with:

- `importLine.indexOf('$') == -1`
- `importLine.replace('$', '.')`

Is there some difference in terms of performance between the use of `equals` vs `indexOf` as validation?

Comment: They have the same Big-O from what I can tell, the lenght of the string. But what you are really trying to figure out here is if something takes 5 nanoseconds or 7. Why is this important?

Comment: @Tobb I just want to confirm that there is not important difference in terms of efficiency between these two implementations. I don't understand why my question is so wrong. Is good when a downvoter give a reason ....

Comment: That depends on your definition of "important". But since you are using java, I take it that your system is not as time-critical as to make any difference in execution time between these two methods "important".

Comment: I don't understand the downvotes either, by the way.

Comment: @Tobb I understood your point and  you are right, the difference in time is minimal and not important. I just want to know with implementation is more efficient.

Comment: @Idos. FYI: I improved my question to study the possibility to re-open it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you are asking are the difference in execution time between `String.indexOf` and `String.equals`. With Big-O notation these are the same, since both (worst case) will iterate through the entire `String` before returning.

In practice, it really depends on the input.

For instance:

- `equals` will return pretty much immediatly if the two strings compared are a different length
- `equals` will return sooner if the difference in the strings occur early (`"abcdef".equals("aXcdef"`) is faster than `"abcdef".equals("abcdeX")`)
- `indexOf('$')` will be faster if `$` occurs early in the string (`"a$cdef".indexOf('$')` is faster than `"abcde$".indexOf('$')`)
- `indexOf` will be slower if the input char is a special character

On modern computers this should not matter, since they are so fast that any difference will be unnoticable, unless the method is called hundreds of thousands of times (or with really large input strings). When optimizing code one should focus on saving seconds, not nanoseconds. With your current problem you should be a lot more worried about making your code readable and understandable to others than you should be worried about which uses the most CPU cycles..

Comment: Wow thanks. I go to wait for others answer before put your answer as accepted. I updated the title of my question.